# WebVR Vive Viewport flickering Firefox 55

Tags: firefox, three.js, aframe, webvr, htc-vive

atm I am trying to create a webVR experience for the HTC Vive on Firefox 55.0.3. It seems there are some performance issues with that. I can not show you code or screenshots from my application, but i also noticed the strange effects of the viewport 'flickering' in the following example from the A-Frame website.

https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/museum/

whenever I look at the center of the room, the viewport starts shaking like crazy. In other examples limke A-Blast this doesn't happen.
Now I am wondering hwhy this happens, as the HMD'S orientation obtained from vrDisplay.pose has to be correct. Then why does the camera, which gets rotated via this pose shakes?

There is also another performance issue with webvr on firefox. at some point, OpenVR/SteamVR just claims firefox is unresponsive, alternating between displaying VIVE Home and the webvr scene in quivk succession.

Did anyone of you also noticed this behavior and has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think perhaps the museum has a hot spot that is not performant. When you look at this certain area, you drop some frames. For the SteamVR issues, I'd file a bug on bugzilla.mozilla.org under the WebVR component under Core. I sometimes get issues not being able to enter VR because SteamVR is trying to boot up Home.

Comment: I've had terrible performance issues with Firefox 55, not just in my code, but in examples from across the net. It's inconsistent too, where with enough F5s you can get it to work smoothly, either for an entire session or a minute.
I've been meaning to follow this up with Mozilla, but so far I haven't been able to pin down some good information on it. I wanted to test it on some of my other PCs first to see if it's just my main dev PC.